# Filter a negative SNR signal whose frequency spectrum lies inside the noise frequency spectrum

Tags: filters, python, power-spectral-density, snr

I am a newbie in Signal Processing and need your suggestion in the following problem. My signal amplitude is 10 times weaker than the noise. Furthermore, the frequency spectrum of the noise and the signal is such that the PSD of the signal falls inside the PSD of the noise window (so convolution or frequency domain filtering is not working at all).

In the figure below, I show the time domain evolution of the signal, where the solid black line is "Signal + Noise". The dotted black line is "Only Noise". The red line represents the "actual signal".

Can you please suggest me which filtering method should I try to know whether the signal is present or absent in the noise? I am trying to implement this in Python.

[image]

And the PSD looks like this (Blue = Noise, Orange = Signal)

[image]

Comment: Please label your axes, or state what they are.  It looks like a time domain plot, but it's not clear.

Comment: While you're editing your question, since you appear to know what the bandwidth of the noise and the signal are, could you *state them*?

Comment: TimWescott: I edited as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: puh, this looks bad. No matter what part of the spectrum you look at, your SNR seems to be always worse than -20 dB. So, while it can be a step in preprocessing your signal, filtering won't help you on its own. Is there anything else you know about the signal, and the noise? Can you put a mathematical model to either? Because this looks so hard, we'll need far more detailed information to solve this.

Comment: What @MarcusMüller said.  There has to be something to distinguish the signal from the noise (like a coffee filter -- the "signal" is the coffee, with everything dissolved into the liquid; the "noise" is the coffee grounds.  So the filter can be anything that passes liquid and maybe super-small particles, but blocks big particles).  If your signal and noise are both essentially random Gaussian processes with the given PSD's, then you have no hope.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If the SNR is little better than -20 dB, then is there any chance that we can detect (filter) the signal? Is -20 dB a fundamental limit?

Comment: @BahauddinOmar only if you know more about the signal. This really won't work out if you don't come up with a mathematical signal model. And that's why Tim and I are very much **asking you to describe your signal**, what it means, where it comes from... with the info you're giving us, no detection can be reasonably made. You know more about the signal, but you're not telling us, so we can't help you :(